# What are different between GCP service and GCP resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm new about GCP.
Differences between "GCP services" and "GCP resources" are confusing me.
I think GCP resource are physical assets such as computers, hard disk drives, virtual resources, CPU and, RAM etc.
But GCP service is the way that I can use for accessing the resources. I think Compute engine, App engine etc. are GCP services.
I watched online courses about GCP fundamentals in Coursera, some of instructors were saying Compute engine and App engine are resources.
I'm not sure.

I want a clarification about the keywords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google cloud platforms have a set of different physical assets like CPU, HDD, VM which are called GCP resources [1] and these resources are used by GCP services [2] like compute engine, app engine etc.

In cloud computing, software and hardware resources become services. These services provide access to the underlying resources [3]. For example here resources CPU, HDD we are using as compute engine services. So If  someone says compute engine or app engine are resources then he is meaning the underlying resources of these services.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview#gcp_resources

[2] https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/cloud-platform-services

[3] https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview#accessing_resources_through_services